# A function I have written returns "None" when called in another program, but when I run that function on its own, it will return an actual value

Tags: python, return

I have written a program to detect and read license plates using OpenCV and Pytesseract. When I run this function on its own, it will return the detected license plate. However, when I try to call this function in another program I am writing, it returns "None" instead of the detected license plate value. Below is the code I have written to define the function.

```
def plateread(filename, directory):

        # import libraries needed
        import cv2 # Computer vision 
        import imutils # image processing
        import numpy as np # for use with OpenCV
        import pytesseract # Tesseract OCR for Character Recognition
        from datetime import datetime # Date and Time information
        import os # file location
        # Location for Python to look for Tesseract OCR files
        pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

        # import & resize image file
        parent_dir = "C:/Users/Sam/Desktop/Fall 2021 Classes/ESET 420/Comm Demo/"
        path = os.path.join(parent_dir, directory)
        fileloc = "%s/%s" % (path, filename)       
        img = cv2.imread(fileloc,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (1920,1080))

        # grayscale image, apply bilateral filter to remove unwanted details
        # bilateral filter applys a blur to details that aren't wanted
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
        gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 13, 15, 15)
    
        # search grayscale image for edges of object
        edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)

        # searches image for contours
        contours = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        contours = imutils.grab_contours(contours)
        
        # sort contours in image from largest to smallest
        # ignore all contours except the largest 10
        contours = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:10]
        screenCnt = None

        # Search contours for an enclosed, four sided contour
        for c in contours:
        
            peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.018 * peri, True)
     
            if len(approx) == 4:
                screenCnt = approx
                break

        if screenCnt is None:
            detected = 0
            print ("No contour detected")
        else:
             detected = 1

        if detected == 1:
            cv2.drawContours(img, [screenCnt], -1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
        
        # Once plate is detected, mask the rest of the image
        # This will result in an image with only the license plate
        mask = np.zeros(gray.shape,np.uint8)
        new_image = cv2.drawContours(mask,[screenCnt],0,255,-1,)
        new_image = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask=mask)

        
        # Crop into region of interest (the license plate)
        (x, y) = np.where(mask == 255)
        (topx, topy) = (np.min(x), np.min(y))
        (bottomx, bottomy) = (np.max(x), np.max(y))
        Cropped = gray[topx:bottomx+1, topy:bottomy+1]
        
        # Read the license plate number using Tesseract OCR Library
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Cropped, config='--psm 8 -c tessedit_char_blacklist="`‘°=-+~,!@#$%^&*()_:;{}[]\|<>?,./ "')
        text = text[:-1]

        # return plate number
        # for whatever reason, when this funciton is called, it returns none
        return text
```

I cannot figure out why this is the case. Any help on getting this fixed is super appreciated!

Comment: Get in debug mode and check out the value of `pytesseract.image_to_string(Cropped`

Comment: I see some hardcoded paths. Does the 'other' program have access there? Anyway, what is this 'other' is important.

Comment: @kgiannakakis The other program does have access to those paths. This whole system is for a project I am working on that is attempting to automate parking lot systems. It includes a client side, running on raspberry pi. The raspberry pi sends pictures to the server, and as the server receives them it attempts to read those pictures for license plates. When I call the plateread() function inside IDLE on its own, it functions perfectly, but when I call it inside the server side code of this system, it only returns none